# How to click a calendar element using cypress?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, cypress, ui-automation

I'm writing an e2e test that is attempting to click a calendar element on the page.  Cypress is actually clicking a number once I open the calendar, but it won't click the Done button afterwards.

Here's the inspected element:
[image: Inspect]

Here's the date picker:
[image: Date Picker]

Here is the code:

```html
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <ion-datetime presentation="date" *ngIf="showPicker" display-format="MM/DD/YYYY" min="1900-01-01"
          placeholder="*Enter your date of birth" formControlName="dateOfBirth" (ionChange)="dateChanged($event)"
          showDefaultButtons="true" (ionCancel)="showPicker = false;">
        </ion-datetime>
      </div>
```

I've tried using the default ID on the confirm button shown in the screenshot.

This didn't work:
cy.get('ion-datetime').find('#confirm-button').click();
nor
cy.get('#confirm-button').click();

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're able to click a number, then shadowDOM isn't the issue since the numbers and the Done button are all under the same shadow root. Could you add the full test please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have other elements which require traversing Shadow DOM then it's a good practice to write `includeShadowDom: true` in your cypress config file.

Then You can directly use the command:

```js
cy.get('#confirm-button').click()
```

Answer (score 4):

You have some elements with shadow DOM on that page, to avoid problems with that try adding the setting `includeShadowDom: true` to the test.

With that in place, both your commands work

```js
it('tests the calendar', {includeShadowDom: true}, () => {

  cy.get('ion-datetime').find('#confirm-button').click();   // passes
    
  cy.get('#confirm-button').click();                        // passes
})
```

---

It can also be set globally in `cypress.config.js`

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
    
  },
  includeShadowDom: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Done button comes with an `id` in the DOM. It's best to use that identifier for your test since `id` should never change during a release.
Using your second example (which targets the `id`), you'll want to correct the syntax.

It should be

`cy.get('[id="confirm-button"]').click();`

If that still does not work, try to include the tag type:

`cy.get('ion-button[id="confirm-button"]').click();`